# Can I send updates to an unpublished app?

Tags: java, android

I made an android app a while back which is being used at work for reporting potential hazards.
It just takes text and an optional image and mails it with JavaMail API to a number of recipients.
We basically only use two phones right now since private phones are not allowed, so the app has been installed and updated by manually download the .apk file and install it.

But now to the question, is there some way I could send updates to an app that has not been published in the play store? It would make things easier to not have to do it manually.

I tried using firebase but this meant that the user had to check for updates. I would rather have a prompt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.